# Caffe: euclidean loss error: Inputs must have the same dimensions

Tags: neural-network, caffe, pycaffe, conv-neural-network

I am using caffe in python. so this is my blob shape:

```
data                        3072     3.07e+03    (1, 3, 32, 32)
conv2d1                    12544     1.25e+04    (1, 16, 28, 28)
maxPool1                    3136     3.14e+03    (1, 16, 14, 14)
fc1                           10     1.00e+01    (1, 10)
ampl                          10     1.00e+01    (1, 10)
-------------------------------- params: name,w,(b)
conv2d1                     1200     1.20e+03    (16, 3, 5, 5)    
fc1                        31360     3.14e+04    (10, 3136)
```

and here is my last 2 layers in proto.txt file:

```
...
layer {
  name: "ampl"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc1"
  top: "ampl"
  softmax_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "ampl"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

and I get this error:

```
euclidean_loss_layer.cpp:12] Check failed: bottom[0]->count(1) == bottom[1]->count(1) (10 vs. 1) Inputs must have the same dimension.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is quite self explanatory:

> ```
> Inputs must have the same dimension
> ```

You are trying to compute [`"EuclideanLoss"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/euclideanloss.html) between `"ampl"` and `"label"`. To do so, you **must** have `"ampl"` and `"label"` be blobs with the same number of elements (aka `count()`). However, it seems like while `"ampl"` has 10 elements, `"label"` only have one element.

Comment: ampl has 10 elements since I have 10 output neurons (10 class) and label has 1 element since it is a number [0-9] (10 class). what should i do? which one to change and how?

Comment: @NimaHatami why are you using `"EuclideanLoss"` then? This loss is for *regression* tasks mainly. It sounds like you are trying to label your data. Why not using `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` (that is cross entroy objective)?

Comment: Thanks @Shai I changed it to SoftmaxWithLoss and it works now!